# Ionic app structure

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic and angular (v2) and I'm trying to understand how the differents sections come together.

I thought that the function you build inside app.components.ts were valid and could be called from every page but when I tried a simple navigation (push and pop) I found out I had to put the navigation functions inside the page1.ts and page2.ts So how does exactly work? Are there no global functions that I can call from wherever I want

Since many of the imports are the same between pages, module.ts and coponents.ts isn't more logical to just have an "imported.ts" file where you import everything once and then import that file in the single pages/modules/components? I haven't seen this anywhere online so I guess there must be a reason but I'd like to know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Angular 2.3` supports component inheritance. So you could wait a little bit more and it would be available in `ionic`. Meanwhile you could take  look into the feature [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2).

To avoid repeated `import` you could modularize your code with `NgModule`. This would bundle the classes in a single module which can be used everywhere else. You can take a look into it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).

Hope it helped.